# How to delete rows using CTE and INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, delete-row, sql-delete

How can I delete data from a table using CTE and INNER JOIN? Is this valid syntax, so should this work:

```
with my_cte as (
select distinct var1, var2
from table_a
)
delete  
from table_b b inner join my_cte 
  on var1 = b.datecol and var2 = b.mycol;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Oracle neither the CTE nor the `INNER JOIN` are valid for the `DELETE` command. The same applies for the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` commands.

Generally the best alternative is to use `DELETE ... WHERE ... IN`:

```
DELETE FROM table_b
WHERE (datecol,  mycol) IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT var1, var2 FROM table_a)
```

You can also delete from the results of a subquery. This is covered (though lightly) in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8005.htm).

---

**Addendum** Also see @Gerrat's answer, which shows how to use the CTE *within* the `DELETE … WHERE … IN` query. There are cases where this approach will be more helpful than my answer.

Comment: The `distinct` in the sub-query is not needed (that is implied with the `IN` operator)

Comment: Thanks - I never knew that. I always thought it would optimize by limiting subquery results, but I never actually checked execution plans to verify. I'll have a closer look at this tonight. Does the `DISTINCT` do any harm in my query?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Oracle simply removed the `distinct` from the sub-query, so I guess it does not matter from a performance point of view.

Comment: I don't know how Oracle really handles it, but from a simple logical point of view it's rather as if the `DISTINCT` was _added_ to the sub-query implicitly. The `IN` operator checks for a contained-relationship that is most quickly handled using some kind of hash or tree. Then,collisions can be handled just on the way.

Answer (score 8):

Ed's answer is incorrect , w.r.t. the DELETE with a CTE (*ditto with the INSERT and UPDATE commands*).
(**You can't use an inner join, but you can use a CTE with DELETE**).

The following is valid in Oracle 9i+:

```
DELETE FROM table_b WHERE (datecol, mycol) IN (
    WITH my_cte AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT var1, var2
        FROM table_a
    )
    SELECT var1, var2 from my_cte
);
```

This particular case doesn't benefit at all from the CTE, but other, more complicated statements could.

Comment: Excellent @Gerrat, and thanks for posting! I never thought of this. I agree that more complicated statements would benefit from this construct.

Answer (score 0):

try below approach:-

```
delete from table_b b where exists (
with my_cte as (
select distinct var1, var2
from table_a
)
select 1 from my_cte a
  where a.var1 = b.datecol and a.var2 = b.mycol;
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to delete records from table1 by referencing two other tables, 2 and 3, so did this:

```
DELETE
  FROM table1
 WHERE table1.var1 = :parameter1
   AND table1.var2 || table1.var3 IN
   (WITH my_cte
      AS (SELECT table2.var3
            FROM table2
           WHERE table2.var1 > :parameter2
             AND table2.var2 = constant1
             AND :parameter2 >= (SELECT
                                MAX(table3.var1)
                                   FROM table3
                                  WHERE
                                     table3.var2
                                   = table2.var3
                                   )
         )
    SELECT table3.var3 || table3.var4
            FROM table3
           INNER JOIN my_cte
              ON (table3.var2 = my_cte.var1)
   )
```

for anyone who's interested, on SQLServer, the order of the various clauses has to be different:

```
WITH my_cte
  AS (SELECT table2.var3
        FROM table2
       WHERE table2.var1 > :parameter2
         AND table2.var2 = constant1
     AND :parameter2 >= (SELECT MAX(table3.var1)
                           FROM table3
                          WHERE table3.var2
                                = table2.var3
                        )
     )
DELETE
  FROM table1
  WHERE table1.var1 = :parameter1
    AND table1.var2 || table1.var3 IN
        (SELECT table3.var3 || table3.var4
           FROM table3
          INNER JOIN my_cte
             ON (table3.var2 = my_cte.var1)
        )
```